# ..dread with a manfiold fear" - manifold? A sentence from an old story

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, literature

I would like to understand what "manifold" here is supposed to mean because it does not make sense to me in its usual meaning (marked by diversity or variety; many..), esp. when used with "fear":

> Now I began to **dread** the city about me **with a manifold fear**: for
> apparently the whole business of the people in Malnéant consisted of
> preparations for the funeral of this lady Mariel.

Comment: Presumably he saw many different things to make him fearful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably dawned on the author that his fear became more ***complex*** than it was before. Instead of feeling threatened from one direction or by one issue, he suddenly realised that the threat comes from ***a variety*** of directions or issues, if I may say so, to point to the meaning of your word. I think the use of *manifold* next to *fear* is excellent here. With one word the author expressed a whole atmosphere.